# Programa no muestra errores al compilar pero no corre correctamente

Tags: c, while, switch

Me pedian un programa con 3 opciones y que cada opcion corriera un programa, ademas debia usar while para que el usuario decididera si queria correr el programa de nuevo o salir. Quise hacer uno sobre conversion de talla de calzados, no muestra error al compilar pero al correr solo sale el nombre del programa y luego me saca. Adjunto codigo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int seleccion, opcion, genero, sistema;
    float zmx, convt;
    const int ush=2, usm=3, eurm=13, eurh= 15, brh=1;
    const float brm=.5;
    printf("1799844 Maria Fernanda Diaz Garcia");
    printf("\nPrograma que convierte talla de calzado mexicano a talla estadounidense, europea o britanica");
    while(seleccion==1)
    {
      printf("Ingrese su talla de calzado (ejemplo: 26.5,24.0): ");
      scanf("%.1f", &zmx);
      printf("\nA que sistema desea hacer la conversion?: \n1. Estadounidense\n2. Europeo\n3. Britanico");
      scanf("%d", &sistema);
      switch(sistema)
      {
        case 1:
            printf("Ingrese su genero: \n1. Femenino\n2. Masculino");
            scanf("%d", &genero);
            if(genero==1)
            {
                convt=zmx+usm;
            }
            else
            {
                convt=zmx+ush;
            }
        break;
        case 2:
            printf("Ingrese su genero: \n1. Femenino\n2. Masculino");
            scanf("%d", &genero);
            if(genero==1)
            {
                convt=zmx+eurm;
            }
            else
            {
                convt=zmx+eurh;
            }
        break;
        case 3:
            printf("Ingrese su genero: \n1. Femenino\n2. Masculino");
            scanf("%d", &genero);
            if(genero==1)
            {
                convt=zmx+brm;
            }
            else
            {
                convt=zmx+brh;
            }
        break;          
      }
    printf("\nEl equivalente estadounidense de su talla es=%.1f", convt);
    printf("\nQuiere hacer otra conversion de talla?: \nSi=1 \nNo=0");
    scanf("%d", &seleccion);
    system("cls");
    }
    getche();
}
```

Asi me sale el programa al correrlo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Apenas voy iniciando con clases de programación, ¿qué podría estar saliendo mal? agradezco de antemano

Comment: Tienes que inicializar `seleccion` a `1` al principio del programa. Si no le das un valor tu la variable tendra un valor basura.

Answer (score 1):

Usa booleanos ([bools](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bool-in-c/)) para ese tipo de comprobaciones (1/0, true/false) y sólo hacía falta asignar 1 a **seleccion** para que ejecute el while que agregaste:

```
// ...
bool seleccion = 1;
// ...
printf("\nPrograma que convierte talla de calzado mexicano a talla estadounidense, europea o britanica");
while(seleccion)
{
    // seleccion = true, lo mismo que seleccion==1
}
```

o si quieres continuar con los enteros:

```
// ...
int seleccion = 1, opcion, genero, sistema;
// ...
printf("\nPrograma que convierte talla de calzado mexicano a talla estadounidense, europea o britanica");
while(seleccion)
{
    // seleccion = true, lo mismo que seleccion==1, no hace falta convertirlo a booleano
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Revisa tu código, el bucle while se ejecuta mientras seleccion sea igual a 1, y esa variable la declaraste pero nunca la inicializaste, es decir, nunca le asignaste ningún valor. Al menos, no la primera vez que se comprueba el bucle, por eso sale sin siquiera entrar.
Cosas como esta nos pasan a todos cuando somos principiantes, pero lo mejor es que una vez descubiertas son muy fáciles de corregir. También es irse acostumbrando a nunca usar una variable que no este inicializada.
Una nota para que sigas aprendiendo: puedes pasar solo la variable al condicional, en este caso del while, ya que el compilador traduce el valor 0 como false y cualquier otro valor como true. En realidad, todo lo que necesita un condicional para evaluar si continua o sí rompe el ciclo es un valor booleano (true o false) así que también podrías pasarle una variable de tipo bool al condicional del bucle. De esta forma, para comprobar si quiere salir, solo tendrías que poner selección a true en el caso de que no quiera y en false para hacer que continúe
Espero que te haya ayudado.

Comment: `el valor de 1 es lo mismo que true, y cualquier otro entero se traduce como false cuando necesita comprobar una condición.` Esto es erróneo. Cualquier valor entero **DISTINTO DE 0** va a permitir que tu bucle se ejecute, es decir, se interpreta como `true`, mientras que para una condición `false` únicamente sirve el 0.

Comment: Ah, cierto. Tienes razón, me confundí ahí. Edito